# JSON data in DATASET attributes

Tags: javascript, html, json

I try to store some JSON data in data-* attributes, but I have encounter one problem:
while I generating source code:

```
<input type="text" data-ia='{"myValue":"One&#039;two&#039;three"}'>
<input type="text" class="input2" data-ia='{"myValue":"OneTwo&quot;three"}'>
```

and when I trying to get this data

```
var myData = input.dataset.ia;
var data = JSON.parse(myData);
```

I've got an error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after 
property value in object at line 1 column 20 of the JSON data
```

And when I looked into the sources the browser shows me:

```
<input type="text" class="input2" data-ia='{"myValue":"OneTwo"three"}'>
```

And I have assumed, that it is a problem, but ho to solve it I have no idea. When i tryed to copy this row it's become more confusing as I paste it:

```
<input type="text" data-ia="{&quot;myValue&quot;:&quot;OneTwo&quot;three&quot;}">
```

My head is ready to blow! Please help me!

Comment: can't reproduce -> https://jsfiddle.net/wcg17pfe/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tk9760sb/

Comment: Why would you have `&amp;quot;`? You're doing something wrong when outputting that JSON

Comment: I trying to make interactive field to store initial value and some other parameters in data attribute in JSON format. It could be a string of text with quotes in it. I need to compare this value (in JSON array) to the actual field.value and make some action in case if they are different.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> {"myValue":"OneTwo"three"}
> ```

The `"` marks the start and end of a string.

You're trying to use one in the middle of a string.

(Remember: The HTML encoding of it as `&quot;` is converted to `"` *when the HTML is parsed* which is **before** the string is read by JS or passed to the JSON parser).

You need to escape it by putting a `\` before it.

```
{"myValue":"OneTwo"three"}
```

or in HTML:

```
data-ia='{"myValue":"OneTwo\&quot;three"}'
```

---

The error suggests that you are generating JSON by hand instead of using a library to do it. Use a library instead, it makes life much easier.

e.g. if you were using PHP to generate it:

```
<?php
$ia = Array( "myValue" => 'OneTwo"three' );
$is_as_json = json_encode($ia);
$ia_as_json_for_html = htmlspecialchars($ia_as_json);
?>

<input type="text" class="input2" data-ia="<?php echo $is_as_json_for_html; ?>">
```

Comment: My final goal is to use this value to fill fields.value [like so](https://jsfiddle.net/tk9760sb/) and compare. but while using double escaping it places escaped value into the field.value....

Comment: I've used PHP to generate JSON, but I use Cyrillic symbols, so I have to use a custom json_encode function.

Comment: The standard `json_encode` function should be perfectly capable of handling Cyrillic characters. Possibly your real problem is that [somewhere the encoding was broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Comment: I will be gratefull appreciated if you will help me to figure out where. if I use a default function, I've geting {"string":"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442, \u041c\u0418\u0420!"} instead {"string":"Привет, МИР!"} wich is bad. Pages and databases all in UTF-8 format (utf8_genetal_ci)

Comment: @AlexanderOlkha — What's the problem? That JSON decodes to the data you want when it is parsed.

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code with the following way -

html

```
<html>
   <body><input type="text" id="myInput" data-ia='{"myValue":"One'two'three"}'>
      <input type="text" class="input2" data-ia='{"myValue":"OneTwo\"three" id="myInput2"}'> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Javascript code :

```
var c = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('myInput').dataset.ia);
var d = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('myInput2').dataset.ia);
```

and it is giving me object containing myValue parameter and its value.

Answer (score -1):

Please check below code for this. It will be helpful for you.

```
<input type="text" class="input2" data-ia='{"ques_id":15,"ques_title":"jlkjlkjlkjljl"}'>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var myData = $('.input2').data('ia');
    console.log(myData['ques_id']);
});
```